# How to Create a runnable jar file from an Android activity

Tags: android

I tried to create a runnable jar file by wrapping an Android activity and the ksoap2 library together. but when I select File >> Export >> Runnable jar "Launch Configuration" field is empty. How can I solve this problem ?

The activity

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;


public class FrameWork extends Activity {

public SoapPrimitive responseWebImplement;
private String SOAP_ACTION;
private String METHOD_NAME;
private String NAMESPACE;
private String URL;
SoapObject request;


public void webImplement(String soapAction,String methodName,String nameSpace,String url){
    SOAP_ACTION = soapAction;
    METHOD_NAME = methodName;
    NAMESPACE = nameSpace;
    URL = url;

      request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

              ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
              responseWebImplement = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             }

        catch(Exception e){

        }
}
}
```

I want to make a single jar file which contains this activity and the ksoap2

Comment: How do you anticipate anyone is going to run this "runnable jar file"? What is your end objective of this exercise?

Comment: Actually I want to create an activity which implements methods of ksoap2 library. Since all my activities need to access a web service I create one activity which has one method to access web service using ksoap2. Now I want to create a single jar file which contains both ksoap2 and my common class. (Then I need to import only that jar to my project)

Answer (score 0):

If your activity has a UI, and therefore probably uses resources, you cannot "create a single jar file which contains both ksoap2 and my common class", simply because you cannot package those resources in a JAR.

Instead, you can [create an Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) that "contains both ksoap2 and my common class", along with any required resources, and you can [use that Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) in your main application project.

Comment: I created a special Android project to create the jar file. This project only contains one activity and imported ksoap2 library. No UIs used. I want create single jar by adding this activity(codes are shown above) and ksoap2. Can I do this ?

Comment: I thin ComonWare is right you can import the Android library project into your project so you don't hav to use a .jar

Comment: @Grant: I have no idea why you implemented that as an activity, instead of a utility class. Regardless, I create all my JARs via Ant and have no experience creating JARs from Eclipse.